# FactoryGirl/Rspec: Validation failed - can't resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Here are my factories:

Users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:email) do |n|
    "user#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    first_name Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name Faker::Name.last_name
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    agreed_to_age_requirements true
    username "testing123"
    state "AL"
    city_id 201
    school_id 20935
    handedness "Left"
    customer_id { "#{rand(1000)}" }

    after(:create) do |user, elevator|
      user.subscriptions << FactoryGirl.create(:subscription, account_type_name: "#{elevator.account_type_name}")
      user.sports << FactoryGirl.create(:sport)
      user.roles << FactoryGirl.create(:role)
    end
  end

  factory :athlete, class: "Athlete", parent: :user do
    type "Athlete"
    recruit_year "2016"
  end
end
```

Subscriptions.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    trial_expiry 30.days.from_now
    active true

    after :create do |subscription, elevator| 
      account_type {create(:account_type, name: "#{elevator.account_type_name}", price: 0)}
    end
  end
end
```

AccountTypes.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account_type do
    name "Legend"
    price 15
    trial_period_days 0
    videos 20
    contributors 15
  end
end
```

Here is what my test looks like:

```
before :each do
  @user = create(:user)
  @sport_user = create(:user, sports: [])
  @school_admin_role = create(:role, name: "School Admin")
  @contributor_role = create(:role, name: "Contributor")
end
```

The problem is that when I create a second user, the Account Type that is associated with the first user's subscription has already been created and so the same account type already exists in my testing db. Any way to write this so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Have you checked out the Dependent Attributes section of the docs?  https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md   -- You might be able to pass an argument in when creating the user, that would be used in creating the subscription, that would then be used to create the account type with a different name...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm trying to get at in my comment above.  If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll delete the answer.

Users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:email) do |n|
    "user#{n}@example.com"
  end

  factory :user do
    email
    first_name Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name Faker::Name.last_name
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    agreed_to_age_requirements true
    username "testing123"
    state "AL"
    city_id 201
    school_id 20935
    handedness "Left"
    customer_id { "#{rand(1000)}" }

    subscriptions {[create(:subscription, account_type_name: "#{account_type_name}")]}
    roles {[create(:role)]}

    after(:create) do |user|
      user.sports << FactoryGirl.create(:sport)
    end
  end

  factory :athlete, class: "Athlete", parent: :user do
    type "Athlete"
    recruit_year "2016"
  end
end
```

Subscriptions.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    trial_expiry 30.days.from_now
    active true

    after(:create) do |subscription, evaluator|
      account_type {create(:account_type, name: "#{evaluator.account_type_name}", price: 0)}
    end
  end
end
```

AccountTypes.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account_type do
    name "Legend"
    price 15
    trial_period_days 0
    videos 20
    contributors 15
  end
end
```

Here is what my test looks like:

```
before :each do
  @school_admin_role = create(:role, name: "School Admin")
  @contributor_role = create(:role, name: "Contributor")
  @user = create(:user, account_type_name: "Free")
  @sport_user = create(:user, sports: [], account_type_name: "Other Free Name")
end
```

Comment: When I use the example above, I keep running into this error: `undefined method account_type_name= for  #<Subscription:0x007fe37cf3aec8>`

Comment: Now getting this error: `undefined method account_type_name= for #<User:0x007fcf13414ad0>`

Comment: You'd do the same idea of wrapping the `subscription` on `User` in an `after(:create)` block and using the evaluator.  Let me know if you'd like me to update my code.

Comment: I updated my factories in my question, but I am still getting the same error for the user. It happens when the user is created in my spec file